# Is it possible to create a Fact table with multiple sql scripts in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Let's say I have four different scripts, and all of the columns will be used to create a Fact table, if I paste these four scripts in the SQL command in the OLE DB Source, would it work? Taking into consideration that I created a table that is composed of all the columns in the four SQL scripts I used. If it's possible... then can I put four different scripts inside the SQL Command in OLE DB Source?? Would it cause confusion in the mapping section even if create all of the columns (in the four scripts) in the table that will be put in the OLE DB destination?

SQL 1:

```
Select r.ResourceID, r.SubSubFunctionCode, r.SubLocationCode, r.Site, SiteDesc, t.Resourceid, sum(ItemValue1) as HoursOutstanding, 
sum(ItemValue1 * isnull(case when itemvalue2 = 0 then CostRateRegOper else CostRateIntOper end,0)) 
as OperCostOutstanding,
sum(ItemValue1 * isnull(case when itemvalue2 = 0 then ChargeRateRegOper else ChargeRateIntOper end,0)) 
as OperRevenueOutstanding,
sum(ItemValue1 * isnull(case when itemvalue2 = 0 then CostRateRegHome else CostRateIntHome end,0)) 
as HomeCostOutstanding,
sum(ItemValue1 * isnull(case when itemvalue2 = 0 then ChargeRateRegHome else ChargeRateIntHome end,0)) 
as HomeRevenueOutstanding,
HomeCurrCode,
sum(ItemValue1 * isnull(case when itemvalue2 = 0 then CostRateRegNat else CostRateIntNat end,0)) 
as NatCostOutstanding,
sum(ItemValue1 * isnull(case when itemvalue2 = 0 then ChargeRateRegNat else CHargeRateIntNat end,0)) 
as NatRevenueOutstanding,
NatCurrCode
from ODS_Staff_Task t, ODS_CurrentResource r
where t.TaskTypeID in (5,6) --missing time
and R.RESOURCEID = T.RESOURCEID
and r.resourcetypecode <> 'C'
and t.sitedesc = r.resourcesite
```

---

SQL 2:

```
Select SiteDesc, t.Resourceid, sum(ItemValue1) as ExpenseToApprove from ODS_Staff_Task t
where t.TaskTypeID in (2) 
group by SiteDesc, t.Resourceid
```

---

SQL 3:

```
Select SiteDesc, t.Resourceid, sum(ItemValue1) as HoldsToRelease from ODS_Staff_Task t
where t.TaskTypeID in (3) 
group by SiteDesc, t.Resourceid
```

---

SQL 4:

```
Select SiteDesc, t.Resourceid, sum(ItemValue1) as MonthlyReviewsOutstanding from ODS_Staff_Task t
where t.TaskTypeID in (4) 
group by SiteDesc, t.Resourceid
```

Many Thanks!

Beau

Comment: Do you want to do it like this (I do not know if will cause confusion that way.), or would you not rather put each script in its own step to root out confusion for the next person looking at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to have one OLE DB source for each SELECT statement and then use a UNION ALL block to, well union all rows. And then you can map the columns in the UNION ALL block to your destination. You will end up with a lot of NULLs though. Since not all columns exists in all of your queries.

Comment: Thank you for this! I can also use your suggestion if I decided not to use multiple Execute SQL Tasks connected to my Data Flow Task.